# jQuery flot, Live plotting from SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, graph, flot, jquery

I have a MS SQL Server which has data being constantly fed to it. I want to make an ASP.NET Webapp or Webpage that can plot the data and update live.

Through research I found that jQuery and Flot are good options. Can someone please guide me in a direction regarding how I would go about this? Im very new to web development. I am little familiar with ASP.NET. I dont know anything about JavaScript/jQuery/flot and was Unable to find good guides in this specific direction.

Things I've tried so far:
WPF-> Limited functionality when it comes to interactiveness, JavaScript feels much more open to functionality.
ASP.NET Microsoft chart controls -> Same as above.

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, if you want your plot update every 0.2 sec. You could do like this:

```
var plot = $.plot($("#placeholder"), {},{} );
var timer = setInterval(function(){
                $.ajax({url: 'url to fetch data', 
                        dataType: 'json', 
                        success: function(data){
                            plot.setData(data);
                            plot.setupGrid();
                            plot.draw();
                       }});
            },200);
```

Answer (score 0):

@VinhBS's approach is an ajax polling technique.  If you want to update "in real time" as data comes into the server, you are looking to implement what is called [comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29). I would read up on the options and decide which is the best implementation for your application (I personally like the "XMLHttpRequest long polling" approach).

Please note that flot will require you to redraw the entire plot each time new data is received.  If you are looking for something that'll "show" the user new data is arriving I would look at the [dynamic update capabilities](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-update) of HighCharts.